# Extract rar archives larger 2 GB on a 32-bit system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I can't extract an 8GB rar file in the terminal. When I try, I get this error:

```
$ unrar --extract largefile.rar 
unrar: invalid archive 'largefile.rar': Value too large for defined data type                                                                                                             
Usage: unrar [OPTION...] ARCHIVE [FILE...] [DESTINATION]                                                                                                                                        
Try `unrar --help' or `unrar --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: If you are running Linux 32 bit, there is a big change you won't be able to extract a RAR archive bigger than 4 GB (or even bigger than 2 GB). You may need to execute your command on a 64 bit Linux.

Comment: hmm, I'm quite sure that rar shouldn't keep the entire file in memory as it extracts, would it?

Comment: @Huygens: Although your concerns make sense, you cannot put that into the question before the OP verifies that that is the case.

Comment: @TFM I thought I had made it more "neutral" in the proposed update. But agreed on the principles. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: "Many system calls that deal with files return values in a `long int` data type. On 32-bit hardware a `long int` is 32-bits and therefore this imposes a 2GB limit on the size of files." ([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Value-too-large-for-defined-data-type))

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on a Ubuntu 16 with an ARMv7 CPU. I managed to unpack a problematic archive with [`unar`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/unar) without problems.

Comment: Nice find! `unar` indeed seems to be capable of handling files > 2 GB on 32 bit systems!

Comment: I unrared a 15gb rar file with unar on Rapsberry PI3 running Raspbian. Life saver. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need the 64bit version of unrar to extract files of this size. There may be a work around to extract this with unrar but I can't seem to figure it out.

If you can re-create the archive use:

```
rar a -v2097152k -R output-file.rar input-file
```

This will ensure that your rar is saved in 2gb chunks and you will be able to unrar it again.

I think the best option for you is just to unrar this file on another machine.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issue on my ARMv7 CPU with 2GB of RAM. Unfortunately using `unar` did not work for RAR5 archives. The solution for me is to use the `unrar` package as opposed to `unrar-free` in the OP.

To install `unrar` we need to enable the multiverse repository.

```
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```